The Taylor polynomial of the function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at $(x_0,y_0)=(3,4)$ is $\ T_2(x,y)=(x-7)^2 - xy +6y^2$
The Taylor polynomial of the function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at $(x_0,y_0)=(3,4)$ is $\ T_2(x,y)=(x-7)^2 - xy +6y^2$
Find the hessian matrix $H_f(3,4)$ and the gradient $\nabla f(3,4)$.
So that's my try for a solution: I'm going to use the formula $T_2(x,y)= f(3,4) + Df(3,4) 
\begin{pmatrix}
x-3\\
y-4
\end{pmatrix}$ + $\frac{1}{2}\cdot (x-3\: y-4) H_f(3,4)\begin{pmatrix}
x-3\\
y-4
\end{pmatrix} $
$T_2(x,y)=(x-7)^2 - xy +6y^2 = 49 +x^2 - xy + 6y^2 - 14x$
Furthermore 49 is the only constant term, therefore: f(3,4)=49.
The problem I have is that I don't know to use the rest of the equation to find the gradient (the transpose of the jacobi matrix).  I tried using the symmetry of the hessian matrix but it didn't bring anything:   $H_f(3,4):= \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}$ Therefore we have: $\frac{1}{2} (x-3\: y-4) \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}$$\cdot$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x-3\\
y-4
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\frac{1}{2}[a(x-3)^2 + 2b(x-3)(y-4) +c(y-4)^2]$
. If someone knows how to find the gradient at (3,4), I will be very grateful. Thank you in advance!

The observation you’re missing, I think, is that the gradient and Hessian of $f$ at $P$ agree with the gradient and Hessian of $T_2$ expanded at $P$. Can you justify this?

Note that the only terms of order $2$, i.e., $x^2,y^2,xy$ will appear due to the Hessian $H_f$ in the second degree Taylor polynomial.
So let us look at these coefficients. From the Hessian, as you compute, we have that
$\tfrac{1}{2} (x-3,y-4)H_f(3,4)(x-3,y-4)^T=b(x-3)(y-4)+\tfrac{a}{2}(x-3)^2+\tfrac{c}{2}(y-4)^2$. So the coefficient of $xy$ will be $b$, that of $x^2$ will be $\tfrac{a}{2}$ and that of $y^2$ will be $\tfrac{c}{2}$. Identifying with the given Taylor polynomial, we recover $b=-1$, $a=2$ and $c=12$.
From this you can write $Df(3,4)=(u,v)$ and solve for $u$ and $v$ after cancelling out all terms of order $2$.

Thank you a lot!
